# Loading Google Maps Autocomplete with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am really struggling to load Google Maps Autocomplete using RequireJS. I am trying the following:

```
define( [
    'jquery',
    'async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places'
], function (
$
) {
    this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('.searchValue'));
});
```

Geocoding loads and works with no issues, but Autocomplete fails with the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I'm at a complete loss as to why this is happening, especially since Geocoding works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the JSONP callback parameter name to the async plugin. In this case, Google's API is expecting a parameter of `&callback=<functionName>`. Adding `!callback` on the end of the URL tells the async plugin to add `&callback=<functionName>` to the request and capture Google's async response.

```
define( [
    'jquery',
    'async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places!callback'
], function (
$
) {
    this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('.searchValue'));
});
```

This should make google.maps.places.Autocomplete available at the time you call it.

Comment: I tried this, and I'm getting the exact same error. I'm not clear on what exactly is causing the error. I don't think the error is about accessing the autocomplete object.

Comment: Sorry. My memory was off. Updated the answer. Also tested it and it works for me.